# Calculate nearest distance to certain points in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, distance

I have a dataset as shown below, each sample has x and y values and the corresponding result

```
Sr. X  Y  Resut   
 1  2  12 Positive
 2  4   3 positive
....
```

Visualization

Grid size is 12 * 8

How I can calculate the nearest distance for **each sample** from **red points** (positive ones)?

Red = Positive,
Blue = Negative

```
Sr. X  Y  Result   Nearest-distance-red 
1  2  23 Positive  ?
2  4   3 Negative  ?
....
```

dataset

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input for others to be able to at least try solving your question. Just providing 2 rows of a dataset and then showing a visualization is not enough. Thanks.

Comment: updated, I cannot upload the whole dataset here since the system won't let me upload

Comment: Please provide the screenshot of the reproducable example then, as it helps understand what you are trying to do. What is the negative and Positive here? in terms of colors?

Comment: Red = Positive, Blue = Negative, I want to calculate the shortest distance for each point to the positive ones ( red ones) i.e new column in the dataset

Comment: How do you decide the size of the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a lot easier when there is sample data, make sure to include that next time.

I generate random data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn


x = np.linspace(1,50)
y = np.linspace(1,50)

GRID = np.meshgrid(x,y)
grid_colors = 1* ( np.random.random(GRID[0].size) > .8 )
```

```
sample_data = pd.DataFrame( {'X': GRID[0].flatten(), 'Y':GRID[1].flatten(), 'grid_color' : grid_colors})

sample_data.plot.scatter(x="X",y='Y', c='grid_color', colormap='bwr', figsize=(10,10))
```

[image: grid]

BallTree (or KDTree) can create a tree to query with

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree 

red_points = sample_data[sample_data.grid_color == 1]
blue_points = sample_data[sample_data.grid_color != 1]

tree = BallTree(red_points[['X','Y']], leaf_size=15, metric='minkowski')
```

and use it with

```
distance, index = tree.query(sample_data[['X','Y']], k=1)
```

now add it to the DataFrame

```
sample_data['nearest_point_distance'] = distance
sample_data['nearest_point_X'] = red_points.X.values[index]
sample_data['nearest_point_Y'] = red_points.Y.values[index]
```

which gives

```
     X    Y  grid_color  nearest_point_distance  nearest_point_X  \
0  1.0  1.0           0                     2.0              3.0   
1  2.0  1.0           0                     1.0              3.0   
2  3.0  1.0           1                     0.0              3.0   
3  4.0  1.0           0                     1.0              3.0   
4  5.0  1.0           1                     0.0              5.0   

   nearest_point_Y  
0              1.0  
1              1.0  
2              1.0  
3              1.0  
4              1.0
```

---

Modification to have red point **not** find themself;

Find the nearest `k=2` instead of `k=1`;

```
distance, index = tree.query(sample_data[['X','Y']], k=2)
```

And, with help of `numpy` indexing, make red points use the second instead of the first found;

```
sample_size = GRID[0].size

sample_data['nearest_point_distance'] = distance[np.arange(sample_size),sample_data.grid_color]
sample_data['nearest_point_X'] = red_points.X.values[index[np.arange(sample_size),sample_data.grid_color]]
sample_data['nearest_point_Y'] = red_points.Y.values[index[np.arange(sample_size),sample_data.grid_color]]
```

The output type is the same, but due to randomness it won't agree with earlier made picture.

Comment: it works fine except for the red points themselves, for example,  I also need the distance value to the nearest red points for red point themselves, not just  0

Comment: That needs a small modification; you would need to calculate the nearest 2 point for all the red, and ignore the first (itself). I will add this later.

Comment: Added the modification, its a little packed, but I used the color coding to get the right distance column.

Answer (score 0):

cKDTree for scipy can calculate that distance for you. Something along those lines should work:

```
df['Distance_To_Red'] = cKDTree(coordinates_of_red_points).query((df['x'], df['y']), k=1)
```

Comment: with this, I can calculate the distance but before the nearest positive point for each point, should be  determined

Comment: Wouldn't the shortest distances best the nearest points?

Comment: Exactly ! nearest or shortest distance to red point

Comment: The query method returns 2 arrays. The first one lists the shortest distances, the second one lists the index of the nearest neighbours (as in DataFrame index). Have a look at that second array to identify which red point the distance refers to.

Comment: I want to automate both steps, 1- determine the nearest red point 2- distance to that red point

Comment: The red points are easy enough to isolate: `df[df['Result'] == 'Positive']['X']` for X and `df[df['Result'] == 'Positive']['Y']` for Y