# Python Recursion Issue (Leetcode 542)

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

I think I misunderstand some important concepts in Python and it is not specific to the Leetcode problem. I greatly appreciate for any help from who knows Python deeply.

The [Leetcode 542](https://leetcode.com/problems/01-matrix/) is that given a 2D array consisting of 0 and 1 only, and for each 1, find the shortest distance to reach 0. I have a dummy DFS solution:

```
  class Solution:
    def updateMatrix(self, matrix):
     
      dists = []
      for _ in range(len(matrix)):
          dists.append([0]*len(matrix[0]))
    
      for y in range(len(matrix)):
          for x in range(len(matrix[0])):
              if matrix[y][x] == 1:
                  self.min_dist = len(matrix)+len(matrix[0])
                  self.DFS(x, y, matrix, 0, set({}))
                  dists[y][x] = self.min_dist
                
      return dists

    def DFS(self, x, y, matrix, distance, visited):
    
      if (x, y) in visited or (matrix[y][x] == 1 and distance > self.min_dist): return
    
      if matrix[y][x] == 0:
          print (x, y, "d:", distance)
          print ('------')
          self.min_dist = min(self.min_dist, distance)
          return 
    
      print (x, y, distance)
    
      visited.add((x, y))
    
      if x > 0 and (x-1, y) not in visited: 
          self.DFS(x-1, y, matrix, distance+1, visited)
        
      if y > 0 and (x, y-1) not in visited: 
          self.DFS(x, y-1, matrix, distance+1, visited)
   
      if x < len(matrix[0])-1 and (x+1, y) not in visited: 
          self.DFS(x+1, y, matrix, distance+1, visited)
   
      if y < len(matrix)-1 and (x, y+1) not in visited: 
          self.DFS(x, y+1, matrix, distance+1, visited)
```

Simply DFS until reaching 0. Every time we call DFS, `distance + 1`. It looks good to me. But a test case `input = [[1,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]` gives me `dist = [[1,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,2,3]]`.

If change `matrix[y][x] == 1` to `matrix[y][x] == 1 and x==2 and y==2` and run the above code, the output is

```
 2 2 0
 1 2 1
 0 2 2
 0 1 d: 3
 ------
 1 1 2
 0 1 d: 3
 ------
 1 0 d: 3
 ------
 2 1 3
 2 0 d: 4
 ------
```

At (x,y)= (2,1) the initial distance is changed to 3. but the initial distance at (2,1) should be 1. My question is why it changes? Can anyone help me point out where I did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65399711/calculate-nearest-distance-to-certain-points-in-python with manhattan distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been taking a look at this. It seems the problem is the way the `visited` set is modified. I think it's being passed by reference which means by the time it tries to go `(2,2) -> (2,1)` the set already contains the point `(2,1)`, i.e the preceding DFS paths have added all their points to it.

I found this article explains "Pass By Reference in Python" well - https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/.

I got your test case to pass by always passing down `visited.copy()`, i.e `self.DFS(x-1, y, matrix, distance+1, visited.copy())`. I'm not a Python expert and imagine there are cleaner ways to handle this though.

Comment: Thank you. I think passing reference could be the issue during recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need recursion for this. You can simply queue positions that need to update their neighbours and keep updating/queuing positions until no more updates are made:

```
def getDistances(matrix):
    rows,cols = len(matrix),len(matrix[0])
    maxDist   = rows*cols+1 # start 1's at maximum distance
    result    = [[maxDist*bit for bit in row] for row in matrix]
    more      = { (r,c) for r,row in enumerate(matrix)
                        for c,bit in enumerate(row) if bit == 0}
    while more: # process queue starting with zero positions
        r,c     = more.pop()
        newDist = result[r][c]+1 # neighbours are at distance+1 from here
        for nr,nc in [(r,c+1),(r,c-1),(r+1,c),(r-1,c)]: # 4 directions
            if nr not in range(rows): continue
            if nc not in range(cols): continue            
            if newDist >= result[nr][nc]: continue 
            result[nr][nc] = newDist  # reduce neighbour's distance
            more.add((nr,nc))         # queue neighbour to cascade updates
    return result
```

output:

```
m = [[0,0,0,0,0,1],
     [0,1,1,0,0,0],
     [1,1,1,1,0,1],
     [1,1,1,1,1,0]]

for r in getDistances(m): print(r)
                  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1]
[2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: @Alian, Thank you very much for the BFS solution and codes. What I am more concerned is about passing the reference in recursion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I want to point out that DFS, as well as BFS, is mainly used for **searching in trees**; indeed, you can think your matrix as a particular tree, but I wouldn't go that path for this task because you don't need to *search* but rather to **keep track of some distance with respect to all of your neighbors, parents and children**.
Moreover, with DFS you will need to traverse your matrix many times to find the minimum for every `1`s and that's very inefficient.

Regarding your question, if you keep track of stack you're creating, you will get:

```
 2 2 0
 1 2 1
 0 2 2
 0 1 d: 3
 ------
 back to (0, 2), with distance = 2
 (1, 2) already visited
 back to (1, 2) with distance = 1
 1 1 2
 0 1 d: 3
 ------
 back to (1, 1) with distance = 2
 1 0 d: 3
 ------
 back to (1, 1) with distance = 2
 2 1 3
 2 0 d: 4
```

Back to your task, since you're using python I would tackle this task by using `numpy`, and look for `1`s and `0`s using `np.where(matrix == 0)`. Then it's just a matter of doing some calculus:

```py
import numpy as np


class Solution:

    def update_matrix(self, matrix):
        matrix = np.array(matrix)

        x_ones, y_ones = np.where(matrix == 1)
        x_zeros, y_zeros = np.where(matrix == 0)

        for i in range(len(x_ones)):
            temp = []

            for j in range(len(x_zeros)):
                temp.append(abs(x_ones[i] - x_zeros[j]) + abs(y_ones[i] - y_zeros[j]))

            matrix[x_ones[i], y_ones[i]] = min(temp)

        return matrix.tolist()
```

If you must not use external libraries, just proceed as follows:

```py
class Solution:

    def update_matrix(self, matrix):
        x_ones, y_ones = [], []
        x_zeros, y_zeros = [], []

        # First scan to save coordinates
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
                if matrix[i][j] == 1:
                    x_ones.append(i)
                    y_ones.append(j)
                else:
                    x_zeros.append(i)
                    y_zeros.append(j)

        for i in range(len(x_ones)):
            temp = []

            for j in range(len(x_zeros)):
                temp.append(abs(x_ones[i] - x_zeros[j]) + abs(y_ones[i] - y_zeros[j]))

            matrix[x_ones[i]][y_ones[i]] = min(temp)

        return matrix
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt suggestion and codes. What I am more concerned is about passing the reference during recursion.